# Using Hyperlink URL in attribute table of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hyperlink, url

I would like to have the URL from an attribute (in the attribute table) as a 'hotlink' wherein you can click on the URL and it opens the browser with the data. As it is right now, I'm having to identify feature, R-click on the URL and copy/paste the URL into a browser.

Answer (score 16):

Take a look in [Action menu](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#actions-menu) at QGIS documentation. You need to define an action, this could be open urls defined by a field.

- Open your vector's properties, go to actions and select `+` button.
- `type` = `open`.
- `Action text` = `[%url_field%]` and click insert.

To ejecute action, click in your object with `Run feature action` button (attributes toolbar).

Answer (score 4):

You have to:

1. Add a text field (PATH for example) to table and place the url to the pdf in the that field.
2. Then go to layer properties and go to actions and add new action
3. Type =  open,  Action text type [% "PATH" %]
4. Select OK and apply.

Answer (score -1):

The feature is implemented in QGIS 3.22

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).