# Creating hyperlink in the attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, hyperlink, url

My dataset contains a list of URLs. There is no hyperlink for the URLs to take me to Google Maps. Is there anything we can create to open the locations in Google Maps directly by clinking on the URL?

I follow the process in this link: https://merginmaps.com/docs/layer/external-link/, but its taking me to the wrong location

Sample links in my data:
Links 1:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/B.S.+Public+School/@25.4506578,81.86350879999999,14z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sB.S.+Public+School!3m4!1s0x399acaa7b51f76dd:0xd05e464cc49ff354!8m2!3d25.4506578!4d81.86350879999999

Link 2:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Satyam+Bal+Vidyalaya/@25.4441338,81.86721089999999,14z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sSatyam+Bal+Vidyalaya!3m4!1s0x399ab5561245cfbd:0x471cbfce000fc042!8m2!3d25.4441338!4d81.86721089999999

Comment: Have a look at [Using Hyperlink URL in attribute table of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217390/using-hyperlink-url-in-attribute-table-of-qgis).

Comment: it wont work for me. Ok and apply not getting highlighted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a text attribute field, insert the URL.
2. In `Layer properties` > `Attributes Form` tab, choose the field, set the **`Widget type`** to `Text Edit` and check the boxes `Multiline` and `html`.
3. Open the attribute table and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the link to open it:

   [image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Add a new field with the name `Link` or any other name you like, a type of `string`, and put the length to equal 300 characters since you have long links.
2. Copy the Google Maps link in the target row.

[image]

3. Right-click the layer and go to `Actions`, select `Open URL` under `Type`, write Open Link in the Description, and select the `Link` field near the expression from the drop-down list, click `Insert`, or write `[%Link%]`, and press OK.

[image]

4. Finally, go to the attribute, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> and it will open the link.