Getting clickable path using QGIS
I import into QGIS a PostgreSQL layer obtained from a simple select.
This layer contains paths pointing to folders on my disk.
I would like to be able to click on it from the QGIS attribute window and directly open the relevant folder.
Do you know how I can make these paths clickable?
a simple example to illustrate my point: **'C:\Users\Public\case_01' is not clickable
CREATE TABLE w_sebio.ce (
id        serial,
name varchar(30),
path  varchar(300)    
    
);

INSERT INTO w_sebio.ce (id, name, path)
VALUES (1 , 'vacation_01' , 'C:\Users\Public\case_01'),
(2 , 'vacation_02' , 'C:\Users\Public\case_02'),
(3 , 'vacation_03' , 'C:\Users\Public\case_03')
; 



Are you willing to turn them into URLs (eg file:///C:/Users/Public/case_01)? If so, you can use the approach outlined in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460438/129409

@Tom Brennan : Thanks

I can create a view with postgresql, import the table into Qgis and create links to open web pages or, as below, create a link to open a folder on my PC.
on the other hand, I still cannot create a link to open a folder located on a remote server such as \ate.... .
file///\ate... does not work.
If someone has an idea..


for a server named 'A' just note:
file://A/...

on the other hand, the path pointing to the directory must not include spaces.
