# Create Google Maps hyperlink in QGIS

Tags: qgis, encoding

I have a feature with fields; point name, X and Y fields.
I want to create a Google Maps hyperlink field that displays the point name in google maps and not the x y coordinates. How do I go about it in QGIS?

Comment: use actions in QGIS see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217398/276

Comment: and then use an URL like this one: https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518%2C-122.3316393 see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started for more information